# Why do d-type bosons in the interacting boson model have angular momentum $J=2$?

Tags: angular-momentum, nuclear-physics, bosons

I'm reading about the interacting boson model in both Wong's *Introductory Nuclear Physics* (1999) and Casten's *Nuclear structure from a simple perspective* (1990). In both books the IBM-1 model is introduced, and so are the s -and d-bosons with angular momentum $J=0$ and $J=2$ respectively.

The bosons are said to consist of *pairs* of nucleons. As far as I know, nucleons (i.e. protons and neutrons) carry spin $\tfrac12$, so a coupling of two nucleons could only result in angular momentum 0 or 1.

Why then is the d-boson assumed to have angular momentum $J=2$? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nucleons can have orbital angular momentum, not just their intrinsic spin. Therefore a pair of nucleons can have essentially any integer angular momentum.

J=0 is automatically of interest because pairing is strong for nucleons coupled to J=0. In many models of nuclear structure, this is the only residual interaction that is considered.

The reason for singling out J=2 as well for special treatment is that we observe that many nuclei have strong quadrupole collectivity, such as quadrupole vibration or rotation of an ellipsoidal shape.